# How to hide featured image in Wordpress Single Post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to hide the featured image in the post page, but not on the home page.
I had a look at the other posts about this same problem, but they didn't work for me, so I will appreciate your help.

Here is my single.php

```
<div id="primary" class="full-width-page">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>

        <?php tesseract_post_nav(); ?>

        <?php
            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;
        ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: open 'content-single.php'   and edit

Comment: In 'content-single.php'  ,in the code there should be get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr )  comment it. and check

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your functions.php (prefer child-theme), and that is it. It works on any theme, and you don't need to touch the ugly HTML templates.

```
function wordpress_hide_feature_image( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) {
  return is_single() ? '' : $html;
}
// add the filter
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'wordpress_hide_feature_image', 10, 3);
```

References:
https://helloacm.com/how-to-hide-feature-image-of-posts-in-wordpress/

Comment: I wanted to suppress featured image thumbnails from all post, page etc. renders (I use them only via a plugin that syndicates images), and I don't know whether this is the best way (or an inefficient or even wrong way) to accomplish it, but I did that by changing `return is_single()` to `return has_post_thumbnail()`.

Comment: The problem with this snippet is that it removes ALL featured posts from a single page. Including the one in e.g. related widgets.

Answer (score 4):

Please, write what theme you are using.
According to what you wrote you have to edit content-single.php.
Search for the line like this:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, ... );
```

or

```
the_post_thumbnail();
```

And remove or comment it.

Answer (score 1):

The code is in the template part. You will find the feature image function in the file named 'content-single'.

There are two ways to disable:

**1. Find the code.**

Remove or comment the function in your `content-single` template file:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <?php
    // Comment out this function:
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr );
    // or:
    the_post_thumbnail();
    // Or you can remove this <div> entirely
  ?> 
</div>
```

**2. CSS method.**

Find the appropriate class of the image div and add a display none condition in your style sheet.

```
.thumbnail{display:none}
```

If you can share the site url I can answer more clearly.

Comment: `<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>` but you have to find the  template part single

Answer (score 0):

**How to remove featured image background from Tesseract Theme single posts:**

**1.-** First of all make a copy from the original *content-single.php* file.

**2.-** Edit *content-single.php* with a plain text editor.

**3.-** If the original file is like this:

```
<?php
/**
* @package Tesseract
*/
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && 'post' == get_post_type() ) {
    $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'tesseract-large' ); ?>
    <div class="entry-background" style="background-image: url(<?php echo esc_url( $thumbnail[0] ); ?>)">
        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    </div><!-- .entry-background -->

  <?php } else { ?>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
  <?php } ?>

  <div class="entry-content">
    <div class="entry-meta">
        <?php tesseract_posted_on(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php
        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'tesseract' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
    ?>
  </div><!-- .entry-content -->

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

*( Source: github.com/Conutant/TESSERACT/blob/Master_Branch/content-single.php )*

**4.-** To remove the featured image background, change it to this:

```
<?php
/**
* @package Tesseract
*/
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

  <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
  </header><!-- .entry-header -->

  <div class="entry-content">
    <div class="entry-meta">
        <?php tesseract_posted_on(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php
        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'tesseract' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
    ?>
  </div><!-- .entry-content -->

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

**5.-** Remember that all changes will be overwritten when you update the theme to a new version. A good option to avoid this is to create a Child Theme, the recommended way of modifying an existing theme. More information can be found at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

**6.-** Test it and let me know if you have any problem.

Regards.

Answer (score -2):

In your code there is one line

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>
```

which means it calls content.php file of your current theme. go to that file and comment following code

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() && ! is_attachment() ) : ?>       <div class="entry-thumbnail">           <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>      </div>      <?php endif; ?>
```

But note that it removes thumbnail everywhere when content.php file calls, so  better idea is create custom **single.php** file. For that you need to copy in **single.php** file and rename with your post name.
for example if you use post for add your content then rename with **single-post.php** or if you use custom post type like news then rename with **single-news.php**.

After that open this file and remove this code

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>
```

from file and goto the **content.php** file and copy your require code which you want to display and paste in your new file.